# nesting "cfloop" tags to loop through pairs

Tags: arrays, list, loops, coldfusion

I'm currently trying to create a `<select>` dropdown list which will choose which `<option>` is selected based on the `URL` variable (or default value). However, I don't want my option list to look like;

name_az, name_za, newest, oldest

As that isn't very user friendly, but i also don't want to be using these in my code;

Name A-Z (Default), Name Z-A, Newest Bands, Oldest Bands

Because obviously that is making MUCH more work for myself.

I could manually create each option list and do a `<cfif>` check on each set of options to select the desired option. However, as any designer will know, this creates a lot of extra, unneeded work when you can create a loop list and simply add two values to that list.

Below is the code i currently have;

```
<select>
    <cfset sortlist = "name_az|Name A-Z (Default),name_za|Name Z-A,newest|Newest Bands,oldest|Oldest Bands">
    <cfoutput>
        <cfloop list="#sortlist#" delimiters="," index="sortpair">
            <cfloop list="#sortpair#" delimiters="|" index="sortphrase">
                <option value="#sortphrase#">#sortphrase#</option>
            </cfloop>
        </cfloop>
    </cfoutput>
</select>
```

I want it to return this:

```
<select>
    <option value="name_az">Name A-Z (Default)</option>
    <option value="name_za">Name Z-A</option>
    <option value="newest">Newest Bands</option>
    <option value="oldest">Oldest Bands</option>
</select>
```

However, obviously I am asking it to return `sortphrase` wherever it is listed, so it will return as this:

```
<select>
    <option value="name_az">name_az</option>
    <option value="Name A-Z (Default)">Name A-Z (Default)</option>
    <option value="name_za">name_za</option>
    <option value="Name Z-A">Name Z-A</option>
    etc..
</select>
```

Is there a way of perhaps creating a `<cfloop>` where I can loop `x` amount of values in a list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your idea of using a nested loop seems wrong to me.  It's ok to treat it as a | separated list, but why loop over it?  You'll just end up with twice as many option tags as you need.  Try

```
<cfloop list="#sortlist#" delimiters="," index="sortpair">
    <option value="#listFirst(sortpair, '|')#">#listLast(sortpair, '|')#</option>
</cfloop>
```

Also, generally arrays perform quicker than lists in Coldfusion.  For something small like this it doesn't really matter, but I would usually use an array instead of a list, at least for the looping over (but probably still using |-delimited list for the two separate parts).

Alternatively you could use a struct for each key-value pair.  e.g. here's an alternative way of doing it using associative array notation:

```
<cfset sortarray = [
    {name = "name_az", value = "Name A-Z (Default)"},
    {name = "name_za", value = "Name Z-A"},
    {name = "newest", value = "Newest Bands"},
    {name = "oldest", value = "Oldest Bands"}
]>

<cfloop array="#sortarray#" index="sortstruct">
    <option value="#sortstruct['name']#">#sortstruct['value']#</option>
</cfloop>
```

OR using struct notation:

```
<cfloop array="#sortarray#" index="sortstruct">
    <option value="#sortstruct.name#">#sortstruct.value#</option>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: That's what I was trying to say, the concept of looping it is in one way "correct" as you want to loop the list itself, but obviously you can't set 'from' and 'to' values on a cfloop list. However, your solution looks like it is the one i need, i haven't seen the #listFirst# and #listLast# attributes before so thank you! I'll try this now.

Comment: Definitely prefer the array idea. That is a more suitable way of doing it than a cramped list. You can read the values a little easier to spot any problems and also creating a new value is easy too. Thank you :)

Comment: I'm having a slight issue, I've copied and pasted your code but i'm getting an error saying "variable NAME is undefined"

Comment: His code should read `sortStruct['name']` or `sortStruct.Name` same for `value`. I've submitted an edit to his answer with the update.

Comment: @Busches thanks for the updates... your edits were rejected by committee it seems, but I've updated my answer to include them.

Comment: @duncan I don't get the edit system here, if it doesn't fix multiple issues then it's rejected? That makes sense. Just kidding. Glad the OP got it working.

Comment: @Busches better than just working. i've managed to revamp my search feature and improve it using the array he provided.